# Get the text of div of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code up to now. i want to access the value 1 of the `<div class="field-item even">1</div`>, and then if the value is 1 add a class, if the value is 0, add a another class. My code only access the first field-collection-container, i can't figure it out the problems.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
        jQuery.each($('.field-collection-container'), function (i, obj) {
            alert($(this).find('.field-items .content .field-item').text());
        })

});
```

the html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="field-collection-container clearfix">
    <div class="field field-name-field-interview-feeling field-type-field-collection field-label-above">
    <div class="field-label">TEXT</div>
        <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">
            <div class="field-collection-view clearfix view-mode-full field-collection-view-final">
                <div class="entity entity-field-collection-item field-collection-item-field-interview-feeling clearfix" about="/dtesthkinterview/field-collection/field-interview-feeling/4" typeof="">
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="field field-name-field-19 field-type-list-boolean field-label-above">
                        <div class="field-label">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="field-items">
                            <div class="field-item even">1</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field field-name-field-no-people field-type-list-boolean field-label-above">
                        <div class="field-label">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">0</div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field field-name-field-untrust field-type-list-boolean field-label-above">
                        <div class="field-label">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">0</div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field field-name-field-waste-money field-type-list-boolean field-label-above">
                        <div class="field-label">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">0</div></div>
                    </div>  
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field-collection-container clearfix">
.....
</div>
<div class="field-collection-container clearfix">
.....
</div>
```

Comment: Can u show the example o/p...

Comment: Better use id for each div.. it will be more easy to retrieve the value..

Comment: @Praveen - how is using id any better?

Comment: because quite obviously css classes can be linked to multiple elements whereas an id is meant to be unique

Comment: because id's will be unique and you can easily pick them with ID identifier as $("#id_name")

Comment: @WimOmbelets - and quite obviously this is exactly what the OP wants...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this sample on jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vijaypatel/Q2GHV/

```
$(function () {
    $('.field-collection-container').each(function (index, obj) {
        $(this).find('.field-items .content .field-item').each(function (index, obj) {
            alert($(this).text());
            if ($(this).text() == '1') {
                $(this).prop('class','One');
            } else {
                $(this).prop('class','Zero');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Above code is woroking fine with multiple "field-collection-container" and also modify odd even elements

Comment: Why do we need to iterate over `.field-collection-container` separately, why not just use a single each with a better selector ? E.g. `$('.field-collection-container .field-items .content .field-item').each(...)`. If the OP only wants to add a class, @Tomalak answer is better imho (more compact and clearer).

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is also possible. but if any processing is required on `.field-collection-container` then above code will be very useful and easy to find out how many `.field-collection-container` are present on page.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.field-collection-container .field-items .field-item').addClass(function () {
    return $(this).text() === "1" ? "one-class" : "another-class";
});
```

Note that you do not need `.each()` at all.

You could use `$.trim($(this).text())` if you expect spaces to be present.

Comment: Nice answer! I would improve the selector: use `.field-collection-container .field-items .field-item` instead, since `.field-item` is recurring on different levels. Or, better, the OP fixes the css classes :)

Comment: Ah, thanks. Done. -- It was meant to give the OP an idea of the idiomatic way to  solve this kind of problem in jQuery. Of course one can always solve something in *more* lines of code. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.each($('.field-collection-container .field-items .content .field-item'), function (i, obj) {
    if($(this).text() == "1"){
       $(this).addClass("someclass");
    }else if($(this).text() == "0"){
        $(this).addClass("anotherClass");
    }
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/P9meu/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">
        <div class="field-collection-view clearfix view-mode-full field-collection-view-final">
            <div class="entity entity-field-collection-item field-collection-item-field-interview-feeling clearfix" about="/dtesthkinterview/field-collection/field-interview-feeling/4" typeof="">
              <div class="content">
                <div class="field field-name-field-19 field-type-list-boolean field-label-above">
                    <div class="field-label">TEXT</div>
                    <div class="field-items">
                        <div ***id="id1"*** class="field-item even">1</div>
                    </div>
```

Instead of calling like this

```
  $(document).ready(function () {  
    jQuery.each($('.field-collection-container'), function (i, obj) {
        alert($(this).find('.field-items .content .field-item').text());
    })
```

});

u can use id for a div and call like this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {  
    {  
       var t=$("#id").text();
       alert(t);
       if(t==1)
          {
            $("#id1").addClass(".classname");
          }
       else
         {
         if(t==0)
          {
            $("#id1").addClass(".anotherclassname");
          }
         }

     })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code and i hope it solves your problem

```
$("div.content").find("div.field-item").each(function () {
                if ($(this).html() == 1)
                    $(this).addClass("evenDivClass");
                else if ($(this).html() == 0)
                    $(this).addClass("oddDivClass");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want the alternating fielditem divs in different classes you could try

```
$.each($(".field-item").find(".even"), function(i,o){ if(o.textContent==="1") $(o).addClass("some"); if(o.textContent==="0") $(o).addClass("other");)
```

Which is short and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a javascript solution

```
var fieldItems = document.querySelectorAll(".field-collection-container .field-item");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(fieldItems, function (fieldItem) {
    var text = fieldItem.textContent.trim();

    if (text === "0") {
        fieldItem.className += " Zero";
    } else if (text === "1") {
        fieldItem.className += " One";
    }
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zpusk/)